# Difference between Data Availability Committee (DAC) and Data Availability Layer (DAL)

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

*'DAC' is an off-chain mechanism to keep data available for verification, which relies on a trusted set of data providers.*

*'DAL' serves data like a DAC, but is a public good provided by the protocol itself: a dedicated rollup data layer for Tezos. So, it's more decentralized.*

Why exactly do we need for L2 a DAC and/or? DAL?

[From Agora](https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/media-attention-regarding-tezos-mumbai-upgrade/5211/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find an explanation here: https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/tezos-is-scaling.html#next-level-scaling and in the article from which the quotes are taken from: https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/smart-rollups-are-coming.html#ready-for-data-availability-solutions.

In my words:

Currently, L2 operations are part of L1 blocks, so smart rollups only partially fix the scalability issue: they address execution times, however block space remains an issue.

A data-availability layer provides a solution to the block space bottleneck, in that L2 operations would not be stored in L1 blocks, instead it will be stored off-chain, for instance, by a "data-availability committee" (DAC).